# TokenObtainPairView con reconocimiento facial

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Un caluroso saludo para todos.

Estoy trabajando en una API de reconocimiento facial, en la cual por medio de imágenes obtengo coordenadas para entrenar el sistema e identificar a los usuarios que ya se han registrado con este método.

La anterior es la primer parte y ya la estoy logrando, sin embargo el siguiente paso es lograr realizar un login con reconocimiento facial que me regrese un JWT (Json Web Token), por lo cual estoy usando la librería rest_framework_simplejwt para hacer este proceso por el método tradicional usando usuario y contraseña.

urls.py

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

**Vistas y serializadores de la librería rest_framework_simplejwt**

A continuación describo los elementos de la librería rest_framework_simplejwt

views.py

```
class TokenObtainPairView(TokenViewBase):
    """
    Takes a set of user credentials and returns an access and refresh JSON web
    token pair to prove the authentication of those credentials.
    """
    serializer_class = serializers.TokenObtainPairSerializer

class TokenViewBase(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()

    serializer_class = None

    www_authenticate_realm = 'api'

    def get_authenticate_header(self, request):
        return '{0} realm="{1}"'.format(
            AUTH_HEADER_TYPES[0],
            self.www_authenticate_realm,
        )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except TokenError as e:
            raise InvalidToken(e.args[0])

        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

serializers.py

```
class TokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        return RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)

        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)

        data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)

        if api_settings.UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN:
            update_last_login(None, self.user)

        return data

class TokenObtainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username_field = User.USERNAME_FIELD

    default_error_messages = {
        'no_active_account': _('No active account found with the given credentials')
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields[self.username_field] = serializers.CharField()
        self.fields['password'] = PasswordField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        authenticate_kwargs = {
            self.username_field: attrs[self.username_field],
            'password': attrs['password'],
        }
        try:
            authenticate_kwargs['request'] = self.context['request']
        except KeyError:
            pass

        self.user = authenticate(**authenticate_kwargs)

        if not getattr(login_rule, user_eligible_for_login)(self.user):
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
                self.error_messages['no_active_account'],
                'no_active_account',
            )

        return {}

    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        raise NotImplementedError('Must implement `get_token` method for `TokenObtainSerializer` subclasses')
```

En este momento no se en donde o como ubicar mi algoritmo de reconocimiento facial para reemplazar el uso de usuario y contraseña.

La idea seria crear otra vista basada en clase que me sirva para este proceso y así realizar la validación por rostro para obtener el `TokenObtainPairView`

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Y donde tienes tu base de datos de rostros? Como almacenas la información biometrica del usuario?

Comment: Obtengo la imagen por el request, la librería detecta el rostro en la imagen y lo convierte en coordenadas; estas son contrastadas con las almacenadas en la base de datos y se retorna el usuario que se identifica en la comparación.

Comment: Con lo que meas dicho ya tienes tu programa  armado, cual es la dificultad que tienes?

Comment: Iniciar la sesión para poder regresar el token, ya que según veo en el código de rest_framework_simplejwt se requiere el usuario y la contraseña y la contraseña no la tengo

Answer (score 0):

He revisado tu idea y la he analizado.
Te dejo unas ideas con código.

```
class TokenObtainSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
username_field = get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD
token_class = None

default_error_messages = {
    "no_active_account": u"No se encontró una cuenta activa con las credenciales dadas"
}

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields[self.username_field] = serializers.CharField()
    self.fields["password"] = PasswordField()

def validate(self, attrs):
    authenticate_kwargs = {
        self.username_field: attrs[self.username_field],
        "password": attrs["password"],
    }
    try:
        authenticate_kwargs["request"] = self.context["request"]
    except KeyError:
        pass

    self.user = authenticate(**authenticate_kwargs)
    user = self.user
    if not api_settings.USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE(self.user):
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(self.error_messages["no_active_account"], "no_active_account")

    return {}

@classmethod
def get_token(cls, user):
    return cls.token_class.for_user(user)



class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

@classmethod
def get_token(cls, user):
    try:
        token = super().get_token(user)
        # Add custom claims
        
        # token['websocket'] = Se puede instanciar un serializer

        return token
    except TokenError as e:
        raise InvalidToken(e.args[0])

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except TokenError as e:
            raise InvalidToken(e.args[0])
        user = serializer.user
        
        return super().post(request, args, kwargs)
    except Exception as ex:
        return Response({'message': ex.__str__()}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Basicamente la clase que necesitas modificar para la autenticación es **TokenObtainSerializer** la que permite modificar el macanismo de autenticación.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).